# Governance voting using a "light mode" client

Tags: tezos-client

Recent v10-rc1 added a new mode to the `tezos-client`, which is called [light mode](https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/light.html).

I wondered if I could use it to cast my vote and which endpoints should I use in `sources.json`.

I did the following:

1. Compiled v10-rc1 binaries
2. Created `sources.json`: `echo '{ "uris": [ "https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io", "https://sebuh.net:8732", "https://mainnet.smartpy.io", "https://mainnet-node.madfish.solutions" ] }' > sources.json`
3. Tested with an RPC: `./tezos-client --mode light --sources sources.json --protocol PsFLorenaUUuikDWvMDr6fGBRG8kt3e3D3fHoXK1j1BFRxeSH4i rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/header`

But I got:

```
Error:
  Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/protocols
     - error: Unable to connect to the node: "Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ECONNREFUSED, "connect", "")"
```

If a basic RPC doesn't work, I'm sure on-chain governance voting won't work as well.

This command works:

```
$ ./tezos-client --endpoint https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io --protocol PsFLorenaUUuikDWvMDr6fGBRG8kt3e3D3fHoXK1j1BFRxeSH4i rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/header

{ "protocol": "PsFLorenaUUuikDWvMDr6fGBRG8kt3e3D3fHoXK1j1BFRxeSH4i",
  "chain_id": "NetXdQprcVkpaWU",
  "hash": "BLKV43G3vo4kGNn3ZczBngydH8XGe854UYToixDx2UHiSeC5g4D",
  "level": 1553826, "proto": 9,
  "predecessor": "BLKxYYxzmdnCauJfzC55LSnnhYqe59MfGbKdGUZ1YNLx3xiSVR8",
  "timestamp": "2021-07-12T10:46:30Z", "validation_pass": 4,
  "operations_hash": "LLoaxS4a5CMAzD55PPrT23gudrrWZSt8yrksun1BGxyU2w5R5ELE4",
  "fitness": [ "01", "00000000000db5a2" ],
  "context": "CoUhrse9ptVYbrpNZkrC3CPETm5trzRd66yBQKntuiQiKLbe2RTB",
  "priority": 0, "proof_of_work_nonce": "706457dc0ed60400",
  "signature": "sigusESabTFWWLKJ9X4qiBkLSHq7J1zSr3dn22JFsC2ByLQ4pQyyHmiYn9YQsPr6Zq7aJ6GUaCryWkGfbjJKM6rK4tkkhq2W" }
```

Comment: That very same command works fine for me locally. However, I'm running the development version of the client, and not the latest release. If you try each of the endpoints individually (in normal mode), do you connect succesfully?

Comment: I just tried on v10-rc1 and it also works just fine.

Comment: You tried the same command at point 3 of my question? I still don't get why it tries to get the protocol from "localhost:8732". I am not running a node, because I just wanted a light way to use Tezos on my old notebook.

Comment: @arvidj I tried the endpoints (edited the main question) and they work as expected.

Comment: I reverified, I think I do exactly as you do. See the trace here : https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2148845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Babell and thank you for your report. Main light mode developer here. I think you found a bug. As `--endpoint` is omitted in your initial request, it is being defaulted; hence the `locahost:8732` showing up. Can you try specifying `--endpoint` as follows?

```
./tezos-client --endpoint https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io --mode light --sources sources.json --protocol PsFLorenaUUuikDWvMDr6fGBRG8kt3e3D3fHoXK1j1BFRxeSH4i rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/header
```

The bug is that, in this case, `tezos-client` should fail and tell you that the value of `--endpoint` should be one of the URLs in `sources.json` (see [this code](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/63612e3a2079aa2b65e0fc2547816f753f361e2b/src/lib_client_base_unix/client_main_run.ml#L209-213)). We chose to force `--endpoint` to be made explicit in the presence of `--sources` but it seems we missed one entry point.

If you confirm that adding `--endpoint` fixes your problem, I will create an issue for this bug.

Comment: I can confirm that, adding `--endpoint`, it works. I think the docs (https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/light.html) can be more explicit, and in one case the example does not include the endpoint (hence, my mistake).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback  I'm making `--endpoint` explicit in the doc (not relying on the default value): https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/tezos/-/commits/smelc-light-mode-doc-more-explicit

Comment: Issue for missing consistency check of `--endpoint` and `--sources`: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/1551